# Creating custom HTML snippets in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, dreamweaver, code-snippets

I'm in the process of moving away from **Dreamweaver** *(I know its terrible but it has it uses)* for email development to VS Code. One handy feature Dreamweaver offered was the use of custom snippets. VS Code offers [custom snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) too but it works differently to [Dreamweaver snippets](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/reuse-code-with-snippets.html) and requires a little more hard work from what I can see. Below is what is happening in VS Code.

**VS Code custom snippet**

```
{
        "Preheader": {
            "prefix": "preheader",
            "body": [
                "<span style="display:none !important; mso-hide: all; color:#FEE4DC; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">text goes here</span>"
            ],
            "description": "preheader for email"
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
<span style=
```

**Expected result**

```
<span style="display:none !important; mso-hide: all; color:#FEE4DC; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">text goes here</span>
```

It seems I have to do some escaping to get the expected result? This would be a little mundane as I could have massive lines of code in my email development process :(

Am I using the correct feature in VS Code to create customer snippets? or am using the feature incorrectly.

Comment: It's nothing more than a quotation issue. Change the double quotes in the style attribute to single quotes. Voila! Problem solved.

Comment: Umm, that is what the pre-exiting answer says....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just your quotes, try:

```
"<span style='display:none !important; mso-hide: all; color:#FEE4DC; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;'>text goes here</span>"
```

Note the alternation of double and single quotes.  Also it doesn't seem as if you can have it the other way around (single quotes around the outside = no).

Or, if you want double quotes in your html, you can escape the internal quotes like so:

```
"<span style=\"display:none !important; mso-hide: all; color:#FEE4DC; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;\">text goes here</span>"
```

Comment: Perhaps my question doesn't reflect the true problem but I will try my best to explain again. Email development relies heavily on tables that span multiple lines  see example - https://codepen.io/reallygoodemails/pen/zjajvX. How can VS code accommodate for these type of situations where snippets are 100 lines long?

Comment: Okay,  I solved your Result/Expected Result question.  And you want to know if snippets are the right way to handle "massive lines of code"?  I would say no.  Look at a task runner and html partials where blocks of html code are injected into a target html file.

Comment: You answered my question to a certain degree I guess. But you didn't explain a situation of how things work with multiline code that could span to 100 lines.

Answer (score 8):

So I found a nice solution to my problem in a situation where long lines of code would need to translate into a VS Code Snippet. This solution is [snippet generator app](https://snippet-generator.app/). Whats great is that it also has options for Sublime and Atom too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Emmet feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) in Visual Studio Code can be very helpful and it is very powerful too in generating HTML code snippet with bare minimum typing.

Let's say, I'm creating [Tic-Tac-Toe game](https://playtictactoe.org/) where I need to create a table of size 3*3 in my HTML file. I'm editing the HTML file in Visual Studio Code. Here is what I write in the editor:

```
table>tr*3>td*3
```

Now press tab. Here is what you get in a flicker of second:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Even while typing the emmet, you also get to see the preview of how the HTML would look like as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: Emmet does not provide custom code snippets. Please read the OP.